# Schrödinger Bridge for other costs

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, brownian-motion, optimal-transportation, fluid-dynamics

Stochastic control formulations of the Schrödinger bridge problem between $\mu,\nu$ are well known (e.g [Chen et al Eq. 4.23](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.10963))

$$\inf \limits_{p_t, v_t} \int_0^T \int \frac{1}{2}\lvert v_t\rvert^2 p_t dx dt \\ \text{subject to   }\frac{\partial p_t}{\partial t} = - 
\operatorname{div}(p_t v_t) + \frac{1}{2}\Delta p_t,  \text{ and}  p_0 = \mu, p_T = \nu $$

which can be related to the static Shannon entropy-regularized optimal transport

$$
\inf \limits_{p(x_0,x_T)} \int \lvert x_T - x_0\rvert^2 p(x_0, x_T) dx - \epsilon ~ H[p_{0,T}] = \inf \limits_{p(x_0,x_1)} \epsilon KL[p(x_0, x_T) : e^{-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\lvert x_T - x_0\rvert^2}] \\
\text{subject to } p_0 = \mu, p_T = \nu. 
$$

I understand this result as the transition probability $q(x_T|x_0)$ of the Brownian motion $dX_t = dW_t$ or $\frac{\partial q_t}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{2}\Delta q_t$ being Gaussian, with $\epsilon = 2T$.   However, most references restrict attention to the Euclidean cost.

I am interested in how this picture changes for strictly convex difference costs $c(x_T - x_0)$, in which the unregularized dynamical OT formulation would be ([Villani Ex. 7.2](https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf))

$$\inf \limits_{p_t, v_t} \int_0^T \int c(v_t) p_t dx dt \\
\text{subject to  } \frac{\partial p_t}{\partial t} = - 
\operatorname{div}(p_t v_t)   \text{ and}  p_0 = \mu, p_T = \nu
$$

However, I am not sure how to relate a stochastic version of this to the static problem, where we would like to obtain

$$ \inf \limits_{p(x_0,x_T)} \epsilon KL[p(x_0, x_T) : e^{-\frac{1}{\epsilon} c(x_T-x_0)}]. $$

Is it possible to modify the Fokker–Planck equation (i.e. constraints in the original dynamical problem) or to induce the desired transition probability $q(x_T|x_0) \propto e^{-\frac{1}{\epsilon} c(x_T-x_0)}$ ?

Comment: I strongly suggest reading Christian Léonard's survey https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0215  where the stochastic point of view is detailed. The starting point (also in Schrödinger's original papers!) is an entropy minimization problem over path measures, with respect to a reference measure of your liking. In the case of the reversible Wiener measure you get exactly what you wrote, but one can cover more general situations. The static cost function is the related to the rate functional in a large deviation problem.

Comment: the link between the entropy minimization and the Benamou-Brenier/optimal-control formulations is then given by Girsanov's theorem

Comment: Thanks! also love your work on Kantorovich-Fisher-Rao :) 

I was aware of the survey, but now notice the relevant parts and see the example $c(v_t) = \|v\|^m$ in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.2564.pdf.   Will brush up on LD theory and try for others as well, unless a solution is obvious

Comment: Actually Léonard 2010 Thm. 4.1 appears to provide the result 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.2564.pdf

Comment: One should always read the surveys, when they exist ;-) I have to admit that Christian's works are sometimes hard to read the first time, but it's really worth on'es time and investments. And thanks for the compliment (funny that you call it KFR, we were the ones to suggest the name and I kind of liked it but it didn't stick, nowadays it's either WFR or HK!)

Comment: I must admit, I use WFR :)   And agree re: Christian's surveys, I am already noticing how much more I learn each time through!

Thanks again for the pointer, this was super helpful